# How could the following function be written using iteration instead of recursion?

Tags: recursion, iteration

How could the following function be written using iteration instead of recursion?

```
function mystery(b)
{
    if b == 0 then 
       return 0 
    if (b / 2 == 0)
       return mystery (b-1) + 3
    else 
       return mystery (b-1) + 2
}
```

Comment: You don't want to make your homework?

Comment: First turn it into a tail recursion; then rewrite the tail recursion as a loop.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question, as it is, does not show any research. A lot of downvotes are normal in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you are doing b / 2 == 0 you are checking whether the number b is even or odd otherwise that is true only for case where b= 0,1.

Recursive function

```
def mystery(b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    if b % 2 == 0:#check if b is even
        return mystery(b-1)+3
    else: return mystery(b-1)+ 2
```

Iterative function

```
def mystery_iter(b):
    result= 0
    while b > 0:
        if b % 2 == 0:#check if b is even
            result += 3
            b= b-1
        else:
            result += 2
            b= b-1
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

At least two people suggest you reformulate the recursion as a loop.  I instead suggest you first try to understand the *mathematics* of what the function is doing before considering unwinding the implicit recursive loop into an explicit iterative loop.  Doing so in this case, you get a simpler answer:

```
def mystery(b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0

    if b % 2 == 0:
        return b // 2 * 5

    return b // 2 * 5 + 2
```

This could be further reduced code-wise, possibly to a one-liner, if one desires.  (Like @AkhileshPandey, I'm assuming that the division in `(b / 2 == 0)` was supposed to be a modulus operation `(b % 2 == 0)`)  The above example is Python 3 as it wasn't clear what language the OP used, nor that the given code would run correctly in said language due to inconsistent use of `then`.